# Cygwin SSHD Service started and stopped in windows

Tags: hadoop, cygwin, openssh

I am trying to configure hadoop setup on my machine (win 7, 64 bit) and I have installed Cygwin for this. during Cygwin installation I have also downloaded and installed openSSH packages required for the setup. on Cygwin terminal I created a service using the ssh-hot-config command but when I start the service an error shows "Cygwin SSHD Service started and stopped".
I am unable to proceed further.

Answer (score 2):

I referred these two links [github](https://gist.github.com/tariqmislam/2159173#file-instructions-and-how-to-L92) and [ebiquity](http://ebiquity.umbc.edu/Tutorials/Hadoop/20%20-%20upload%20data.html) to setup hadoop on my windows 7 PC, in both the links it is clearly mentioned to say "NO" when "Should privilege separation be used?" (refer point 9 of github link) but that doesn't work for me and it continued to give me the same error.

So I tried giving option Yes while installing Cygwin and guess what it worked smoothly!